# Configuring AutoMapper with Lists and Enums

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I'm currently configuring AutoMapper as I need to convert a list of Person(s) to a list of PersonViewModel(s). I have flattened out the Repository for my `ViewModel`, see below:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public List<CalendarEntry> Days { get; set; }
}
public class CalendarEntry
{
    public int CalendarEntryId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }    
    public Days Day { get; set; }    
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }  
}
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }   
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public bool IsMonday { get; set; }
    public bool IsTuesday { get; set; }
    public bool IsWednesday { get; set; }
    public bool IsThursday { get; set; }
    public bool IsFriday { get; set; }

    public DateTime? MondayFrom { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? MondayTo { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? TuesdayFrom { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? TuesdayTo { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? WednesdayFrom { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? WednesdayTo { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? ThursdayFrom { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? ThursdayTo { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? FridayFrom { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? FridayTo { get; set; }     
}
```

I have created an `AutoMapperConfig` file where I have Created a Map for each member like so:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PersonId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PersonId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PersonName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
```

Now, I have reached the CalendarEntryId and obviously this is contained within the `List<CalendarEntry> MeetingDays` prop, how do I handle this property and also the 5 bools for Mon-Fri, when the user creates the record from the front end they are selecting check boxes and entering a time field, the rest of the `DateTime` (day/month/year) is being set to `01/01/1900` in the database. Days is an `Enum` with Mon-Sun stored so I am able cross reference somehow to check whether for example `IsMonday` should be true or false, but I'm getting a tad confused with how to configure this part of `AutoMapper` up?

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect to map a list of ids to one int property `CalendarEntryId`?

If I was you, I would change my view model to contain a collection of `CalendarEntryViewModel`'s.

Create a map `CreateMap<CalendarEntry, CalendarEntryViewModel>` and then Automapper would map your `List<CalendarEntry>` to your `List<CalendarEntryViewModel>` on your view model.

Also, since your data model and view model have the same property name for PersonId you don't need to explicitly map that. Automapper will do this for you.

Comment: Good point about the CalendarEntryId, I will remove that from my view model as I don't really care about that in the web front end, I still however want to map my CalendarEntry list into a flat packed set of bools/DateTimes for the ViewModel